# Alpine Linux becomes unreachable after a certain period of inactivity

Tags: linux, ssh, alpine-linux, hibernate, sleep

I have installed Alpine Linux as OS for a mini server.
I have correctly configured the server to be reached via ssh (openSSL) and my programs run on docker containers.
I use a wired connection.

The problem is that after a certain period of inactivity (no requests to the server), it seems as if the server disconnects from the internet.
I can no longer connect it via ssh, and it also disappears from the list of connected devices.

I have been looking for methods to disable sleep/hibernation of the OS and network card but found nothing.

When I move the touchpad it becomes reachable again.

I hope you can help me and thank you in advance.

PS
I use Alpine Linux because the hardware is old and I need to use as little ram as possible.

UPDATE - SYSLOG:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages


Feb 20 01:00:00 cron.info crond[2158]: <user> pid 6301 cmd run-parts /etc/periodic/hourly

Feb 20 01:15:00 cron.info crond[2158]: <user> pid 6303 cmd run-parts /etc/periodic/15min

Feb 20 01:30:00 cron.info crond[2158]: <user> pid 6304 cmd run-parts /etc/periodic/15min

Feb 20 01:45:00 cron.info crond[2158]: <user> pid 6306 cmd run-parts /etc/periodic/15min

Feb 20 02:00:00 cron.info crond[2158]: <user> pid 6308 cmd run-parts /etc/periodic/15min

Feb 20 02:00:00 cron.info crond[2158]: <user> pid 6309 cmd run-parts /etc/periodic/hourly

Feb 20 02:00:00 cron.info crond[2158]: <user> pid 6310 cmd run-parts /etc/periodic/daily

Feb 20 02:15:00 cron.info crond[2158]: <user> pid 6312 cmd run-parts /etc/periodic/15min

Feb 20 02:30:00 cron.info crond[2158]: <user> pid 6314 cmd run-parts /etc/periodic/15min

Feb 20 02:39:39 auth.info sshd[6316]: Accepted publickey for <user> from <ip> port <port> ssh2: RSA
```

Comment: Is there any DE/WM installed or just CLI?

Comment: No DE, I am using the CLI proposes by the OS after installation

Comment: Could you check the syslog to make sure that the notebook indeed goes to suspend? I suspect you are using openrc, is that right?

Comment: Yes exactly, Alpine as default use openrc.